# eViews: save quarterly data in workfile with 10min frequency

Tags: excel, dataset, finance, economics, eviews

I have a dataset (in Excel) consisting of quarterly observations.
For each of these Observations, I also have an exact date and time, like:
Obs.value, 20000101, 07:00.

Also I created an eViews Workfile with 10 Minute frequency.
Now I want to import that quarterly data to the eViews workfile.
For all (10min frequency) observations where there is no corresponding value in the data, the observation value should be zero. That means in the end I need to have a 10 Min frequency vector with one observation value per quarter and zeros otherwise:

.
.
.
.

20000101, 06:50, 0

20000101, 07:00, Obs. Value (one per quarter)

20000101, 07:10, 0

.
.
.

Does anyone know how to programm that in eViews?

Answer (score 0):

For those finding this...looks like it was resolved over on the Eviews forums.

http://forums.eviews.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9068